# AdaBoost algorithm Hyperparameter Tuning MLR

Tags: r, machine-learning, multiclass-classification, mlr, adaboost

Im trying to tune the hyperparameters of the AdaBoost algorithm. The goal is to train a model with a multiclass classification variable as target. Im working with the MLR package in R. However, MLR does only give letters (see below) so Im not sure what these variables are. Does anyone know where I can find this information?

```
filterParams(getParamSet("classif.adaboostm1"), tunable = TRUE)
```

Gives

```
     Type len                     Def      Constr Req Tunable Trafo
P integer   -                     100   90 to Inf   -    TRUE     -
Q logical   -                   FALSE           -   -    TRUE     -
S numeric   -                       1 -Inf to Inf   -    TRUE     -
I integer   -                      10    1 to Inf   -    TRUE     -
D logical   -                   FALSE           -   Y    TRUE     -
W untyped   - <unnamed>=DecisionStump           -   -    TRUE     -
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the hyperparameters provided by the learner. You can find more information in its documentation: https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/meta/AdaBoostM1.html